# Defining muliple hash functions for the same object

Tags: java, hash

I have several Sets that store the objects of the same class, but I want to specify a different identity function for each of them (i.e. say, in one set A==B if A.x==B.x, while in another A==B if A.y==B.y).

Currently I use TreeSets with different Comparators defined for each. I am wondering how the same thing can be done if I want to switch to HashSets. Java does not allow passing a separate hash function in the same way it allows Comparators for Sorted/Tree-based Collections. The only way that I can think of doing it would involve creating a different wrapper class and implementing the hashCode() method in each for the elements of each HashSet. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using THashSet in [GNU Trove](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/), This support multiple hashing strategies.

Answer (score 7):

How about creating separate subclasses for each set.  The only difference for each subclass would be the overridden hash function that meets your criteria.

Comment: You could implement the subclasses as private inner classes and provide a factory method to obtain the equality semantics you want.  This encapsulates the choice completely

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a better way to do it. Your proposed solution (wrapper classes with different comparison logic) sounds very reasonable.

You mentioned implementing the `hashCode` method - don't forget to implement `equals` as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option: You can copy the source for `HashMap` and replace the method `hash(Object key)` with something else (for example, a call to a `Hasher` that works like the `Comparator` of the `TreeMap`).

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the best thing to do. I am accepting Peter Lawry's answer since he suggests using an off-the-shelf implementation instead of coding my own.